# Ngfileupload - How to show image name of rejected files?

Tags: image, angular, upload, ng-file-upload

I have created this [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iem_usman/dneLebqc/) i get the rejected file error message but how can I get the file name which is rejected ? Or is there a easier way to implement this task ?  I am uploading multiple files , and have put a check on them, that no file should be greater than 1 MB. Here is my code

```
    <body ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <h4>Upload on file select</h4>

    <button ngf-select="uploadFiles($files)" multiple 
            accept="image/*" ngf-model-invalid="invalidImages" ngf-max-size="1MB">Select Files</button>
    <br>
    {{invalidImages[0].$error}}
    <br>Files:
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="f in files" style="font:smaller">
            {{f.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <span class="progress" ng-show="progress >= 0">
        <div style="width:{{progress}}%" ng-bind="progress + '%'"></div>
    </span>
    {{errorMsg}}
</body>

    //inject angular file upload directives and services.
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
    $scope.uploadFiles = function (files) {
        $scope.files = files;
        if (files && files.length) {
            Upload.upload({
                url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
                data: {
                    files: files
                }
            }).then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.result = response.data;
                });
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0) {
                    $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
                }
            }, function (evt) {
                $scope.progress = 
                    Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```